# Typescript bug? Correctly typed array method with "Parameter 'x' implicitly has an 'any' type" error

Tags: typescript

I'm mapping over an array called `matches` with the type signature `Match[]`, and I've got `noImplicitAny` set to true.

Given this code:

```
matches.find(m => !m.foo)
```

I would expect Typescript to infer that each element in the array is of type `Match`, but for some reason I receive the error:

```
Parameter 'm' implicitly has an 'any' type.
```

I know that I can technically fix this by explicitly typing the function argument like so:

```
matches.find((m: Match) => !m.foo)
```

But I would strongly prefer Typescript just infer the type signature like it is designed to do.

Does anyone know why this might be occurring?

Comment: Could you provide a full sample that reproduces the issue. What you describe so far works as it should inferring the parameter: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAmQWTmBALZBvZGAeyIC5kBnMKUAc2QF8AoAEwgQBs4oUA3b5AFtMOCBXIYs2ANoBdJsKliAdDFAsAFIOQBeAHzIAhINUkAlEA